# Yii2 Как настроить URL на двух сайтах, которые находятся на 1м домене?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, домен

Имеется домен site.ru. На нём сайт.

На site.ru/site2 - находится другой сайт, который написан на yii2.

Собственно до переноса с локалки на этот домен, был настроен ЧПУ и всё работало нормально. Теперь выскакивает ошибка 404 при переходе на страницы, которые, как видимо, обрабатывает движок site.ru: site.ru/site2/admin/... = error

Comment: Попробуйте настроить все как вам надо через `.htaccess`

Answer (score 2):

Если я всё правильно понял, то нужно добавить в конфигурационном файле базовый URL сайта, а именно

```
return [
    ...
    'components' => [
        ...
        'urlManager' => [
            ...
            'baseUrl' => 'http://site.ru/site2' //Эта строчка
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: Не хочет работать. Может надо настроить .htaccess? В корне сайта стоит стандартный. У меня структура такая, что иницилизирующий приложение файл index.php находится в корне сайта. папки web нету.

Comment: Разницы нету, есть директория web или нет, если правильно прописаны пути к файлам composer, то всё нормально будет. А вот что касается .htaccess на базовой директории, то тут, к сожалению, экстрасенсорика не работает. Нужно знать, как выглядит содержимое основного .htaccess и что вообще там за система в корне.

Comment: @brusens вот у меня доступа туда и нету((